# Export ssrs report to excel in 1 sheet

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have two tablix in ssrs. I want all the data in the first Tablix in sheet 1, but when I export my ssrs report to excel, it breaks it down to 10 sheets.The second tablix is on the 11th sheet, which i want to be the second sheet. I Added "a page break after" on the first tablix but it is still splitting up the data from the first tablix. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a Page Break on a Row or Column Group in the first table that is causing it to create pages for each Group.

Click on the table and click on the drop down by the Grouping for each Group at the bottom and go to the Group Properties.

[image]

Then go to the Page Break tab and make sure that the Page Break property box is unchecked.

[image]